# ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF'], dtype='<U10')

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have face this error of `pos_label` firstly I import this library

```py
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
```

because of **Version error** I again import this library

```py
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
```

This is my code for running:

```
depth_range = range(1, 10)
jaccard_similarity_score_ = []
f1_score_ = []

for d in depth_range:
    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'gini', max_depth = d)
    dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
    dt_yhat = dt.predict(X_test)
    ja = jaccard_score(y_test, dt_yhat, "yes")
    jaccard_similarity_score_.append(ja)
    f1_score_.append(f1_score(y_test, dt_yhat, average = 'weighted'))
```

I get this error :

> ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF'], dtype='<U10')

Comment: Hi, can you show us the data set a bit? like maybe the first 5 rows and the names of the columnes? otherwise I think there is not enough information to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention `pos_label` value to the category which you want to predict as 1. So, for your case, `PAIDOFF` will be a positive label, so include `pos_label='PAIDOFF'`.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line change the same to:

```
f1_score(y_test, dt_yhat, average = 'weighted', pos_label="PAID_OFF")
```